# Crude odds ratio

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, inference, odds-ratio, odds

I came across following definition of crude odds ratio in binary logistic regression:

> Crude odds ratio is when you have only one independent variable

And also I heard:

> Crude odds ratio is when you have only one binary independent variable (2x2 table)

Which is proper one?

Comment: Well, to have an independent variable implies you must also have a dependent variable (binary) as well as a model (binary logistic regression). Both of your definitions omit this important information, so I would strike them off on those grounds.

Comment: I think a better terminology for the odds ratio you invoke is "unadjusted" (rather than "crude") - for that definition to make sense, you must also have other independent variables and/or covariates you are not adjusting for in your model.

Comment: Hi, Isabella thanks for noticing lack of "binary", I corrected that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The former definition is correct. Logistic regression gives us a notion of odds ratios for continuous regressors. In the past, we preferred binary regressors because the models could be calculated without technology. Now we have a broader perspective because of our computational power.

Comment: Could you give paper or book or any other reliable source, which confirms this?

Comment: @mokebe I believe modern epidemiology by Rothman has such a discussion. The term is not a mathematical one, but rather one of causal modeling and epidemiology.